# Is it legal to say "Let's Go Brandon" on amateur radio?

Tags: united-states, radio, amateur-radio

"No amateur station shall transmit... obscene or indecent words or language..."

Saying the original phrase Let's Go Brandon was derived from would certainly violate this, but would saying Let's Go Brandon be an issue?

As a comment by user sonyfreak points out, quoting the Wikipedia article ["Let's Go Brandon"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%27s_Go_Brandon):

> "Let's Go Brandon" is a political slogan and Internet meme that has been used as a [minced oath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minced_oath) for "Fuck Joe Biden", in reference to Joe Biden, the 46th president of the United States.

Comment: Broadcast content is full of euphemistic phrases standing in for spicier content.  Why would this be any different?

Comment: Can you explain who, or what, is a Brandon please?

Comment: "Let's Go Brandon" is a political slogan and Internet meme that has been used as a minced oath for "Fuck Joe Biden", in reference to Joe Biden, the 46th president of the United States.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%27s_Go_Brandon

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can "obscenity" be used to forbid a political sign?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/67985/can-obscenity-be-used-to-forbid-a-political-sign)

Comment: https://www.fcc.gov/general/obscenity-indecency-and-profanity

Comment: My question was mostly asking if "Let's Go Brandon" is obscene or indecent. The phrase it stands for is, but is it?

Comment: The alleged duplicate is in fact not a duplicate, because radio and other broadcast media are, in the US, subject to a level of regulation, specifically for "indecency" that would be unconstitutional when applied to signs or print media, including the internet. The comments add the needed details, I will edit them into the question.

Comment: Also, this question is specifically about **amateur** radio, **not** any form of broadcasting.

Comment: @Someone, Amateur radio **is** a form of broadcasting. It is subject to some (but not all) of the same rules as commercial broadcasting, and some specific rules of its own, But it is still regulated more strictly than any print or text medium

Comment: @DavidSiegel no, it is not a form of broadcasting. It is held to an even stricter standard of obscenity/indecency restrictions, but it is not intended for reception by the general public, and is therefore not broadcasting.

Comment: "An amateur station shall not engage in any form of broadcasting..." (Title 47Part 97.113b)

Comment: Broadcasting. Transmissions intended for reception by the general public, either direct or relayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official FCC page ["Obscene, Indecent and Profane Broadcasts"](https://www.fcc.gov/consumers/guides/obscene-indecent-and-profane-broadcasts):

> **Indecent content** portrays sexual or excretory organs or activities in a way that is patently offensive but does not meet the three-prong test for obscenity.

This page does not cite any laws or sources. The "three-prong test" would ber the rule from [*Miller v. California*, 413 U.S. 15 (1973)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_v._California)

A minced oath such as "Let's Go Brandon" would not **appear** to violate this rule.

Violations of the rule against indecent content that the FCC may penalize are known as ["Actionable indecency"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actionable_indecency). These rules originated in the case [*Federal Communications Commission v. Pacifica Foundation*, 438 U.S. 726 (1978)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FCC_v._Pacifica_Foundation) but have since been modified by the FCC.

Such violations may be penalized under [47 USC 502](https://codes.findlaw.com/us/title-47-telecommunications/47-usc-sect-502.html) or [47 USC 503](https://codes.findlaw.com/us/title-47-telecommunications/47-usc-sect-503.html)

Lili Levy, in [*The FCC's Regulation of Indecency*](https://web.archive.org/web/20151123162402/http://www.firstamendmentcenter.org/madison/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/FirstReport.Indecency.Levi_.final_.pdf) (April 2008) has argued that these modified rules may not be constitutional as applied.

[47 USC 152](https://codes.findlaw.com/us/title-47-telecommunications/47-usc-sect-152.html) defiens the scope of this chapter as:

> The provisions of this chapter shall apply to all interstate and foreign communication by wire or radio and all interstate and foreign transmission of energy by radio, which originates and/or is received within the United States, and to all persons engaged within the United States in such communication or such transmission of energy by radio, and to the licensing and regulating of all radio stations as hereinafter provided;  but it shall not apply to persons engaged in wire or radio communication or transmission in the Canal Zone ...

[47 USC 153](https://codes.findlaw.com/us/title-47-telecommunications/47-usc-sect-153.html) the definitions section of this law) specifies that:

> The term “amateur station” means a radio station operated by a duly authorized person interested in radio technique solely with a personal aim and without pecuniary interest.
>
> ...
>
> The term “broadcast station”, “broadcasting station”, or “radio broadcast station” means a radio station equipped to engage in broadcasting as herein defined.
>
> ...
>
> The term “broadcasting” means the dissemination of radio communications intended to be received by the public, directly or by the intermediary of relay stations.

Comment: That's probably correct, but as I mentioned above, amateur radio is not broadcasting. Amateur transmissions are not intended to be received by the public, directly or by the intermediary of relay stations. They are intended to be received only by other licensed amateur operators, although they certainly can be received by the public.

Comment: Transmitting "CQ CQ CQ Let's Go Brandon" would be illegal on amateur radio, because it is broadcasting the operator's political views. What I'm asking about would be e.g. in a conversation, one person mentions gas prices, and the other person replies "let's go Brandon."

Comment: The definition of indecent content should be the same for both, though, so it should be fine.